# The curious case of the Arrays class

Tags: java

In Java, there is an amazing class called `Arrays (java.util.Arrays)`. Whenever we create an array object, is it an object of the same `Array` class?

If so, why is it not called as follows:

```
Arrays arrayName<type> =  new Arrays<type>[size];
```

as all the other objects of predefined java classes are?
And instead called this way:

```
type arrayName = new type[size];
```

Comment: `Arrays` is a class full of static methods. It's not a type you need to instantiate. There's no type called `Array` in Java.

Comment: You're confusing [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) with arrays.

Comment: Note that `util` in `java.util.Arrays` :)

Comment: Yes, that's my question. Are they actually different? In what way?

Comment: They are fundamentally different, in every way. I'm serious :p

Comment: Well, just when I thought I was fine with the basics... :(

Comment: And  -5 points as an insult to injury.

Comment: Just read up on primitives and check out that Arrays documentation. You'll get it.

Comment: Ok, thanks buddy. I've been reading this really nice book Big Java Early Objects but failed to pick this up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there is no reason to do so. It contains `static` methods which can be accessed without instatiating the class.

Comment: Hmmm...I didn't know that. But I know what a static class method is. Interesting. Please add something more.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked

Answer (score 0):

If you check out [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) from the Java website, you'll notice that this is a utilitarian class for creating Arrays using `static` methods, primarily meant for reflection tasks. Such classes are for creating and modifying arrays as a general concept, not as a parent object.